# ffmpeg speed encoding problem

Tags: ffmpeg, encoder

I am currently developing an application that makes capturing video from a webcam on Linux using the Qt Designer tool and V4L2 and ffmpeg libraries under C + +, to capture the image there is no problem using lib V4L2, and since That a picture is ready I send it to the encoder which is based on ffmpeg libs, initially the encoder creates a video file, and it receives images to encode it in this file, my problem is as follows: the encoding is normally done, but  after if I start playing the recorded video file, speed appears to be accelerated compared to the regular speed! So what is clear, the problem is in video encoding,
my question is, is there a method or function that manages ffmpeg encoding speed pictures ?????
thank you for your help.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with C++ or Qt, please tag appropriately.

Comment: i just wanted to cralify my problem, because i'm using Qt, programming in c++ language.

Comment: But people with just C++ and Qt knowledge cannot help you, although they might be 'monitoring' those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a custom encoded video with FFMpeg, you'll actually need to set the PTS on each AVPacket that gets written to the output file. Setting the time_base of your AVCodecContext will only tell the container what to expect. The PTS (Presentation Time Stamp) tells the decoder (when you view your video) when to actually display that particular frame.

For example:

I have an AVFrame that i got from the V4L2 part of FFMpeg. To start, its safer to make a copy of this image using av_picture_copy. (So the encoder does not look at all the extra info in the AVFrame struct.)

```
av_picture_copy( (AVPicture*) picture, (AVPicture*) pFrame, c->pix_fmt, c->width, c->height );

picture->pts = numFrames;
```

now set the pts based on num of encoded frames

```
pDestFrame->pts = numFrames;
```

now encode

```
numEncodedBytes = avcodec_encode_video( AVCodecCtx, buffer, bufferSize, pDestFrame );
```

NOW Create an AVPacket and set the timestamp again, after rescaling

```
AVPacket pkt;
av_init_packet(&pkt);

pkt.pts = av_rescale_q( c->coded_frame->pts, c->time_base, mpVideoStr->time_base );

if ( c->coded_frame->key_frame ) pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

pkt.stream_index = mpVideoStr->index;
pkt.data = outbuf;
pkt.size = out_size;
```

Finally, you can write the packet out

```
av_write_frame( formatCtx, &pkt );
```

I know this works for H264 video encoding, but I'm not 100% sure it works for other types of video, since i was only concerned with H264 when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add time stamps to your pictures.
FFMpeg will do the encoding/decoding as fast as possible. You need to write a synchronization yourself. Usually in video decoding and playback you have timestamps attached to your frames or at least you can create some with the audio clock and your frame rate.
But this highly depends on how you want to sync and how you implemented it.
Maybe the [tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial05.html) of FFMpeg gives you some additionl hints

Comment: i had seen this tutorial, but this one is dedicated for decoding function, my decoder works fine, more than that, i just captured the video stream without audio to make it easier, that's why i think strongly tat the problem is in the decoder, for the moment, i'm modifying the pts in the encoder, specially of the  formatcontext, packet...

Comment: You can see in the tut how the syncing is done. In this case how the video is synced up to the audio. In your case I assume there is no audio. So you need to determine how long a video frame needs to be displayed. For example by using a frame rate or a duration for each frame.

Comment: sorry i mean the problem is in the "ENCODER" because the decoder works fine and if i play the recorded video by a player(like vlc) it seems to be accelerated too, so the problem is in the encoder.

Comment: Ok I thought it is only in your app. But if the stream is wrong in general than it is really about wrong timestamps. You can look at Beckett answer. You need to set the frame rate for the context and a pts value for each AVPicture you want to encode. That should provide enough infos for playback

Comment: i think it has been done, take a look : i used this in my createfile function `pCodecCtx->bit_rate = Bitrate; pCodecCtx->width = getWidth(); pCodecCtx->height = getHeight(); pCodecCtx->time_base.den = 24; pCodecCtx->time_base.num = 1; pCodecCtx->gop_size = Gop; pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = ffmpeg::PIX_FMT_YUV420P;` and this one for th packet pts : `if (pCodecCtx->coded_frame->pts != ((unsigned)0x8000000000000000LL)) pkt.pts= av_rescale_q(pCodecCtx->coded_frame->pts, pCodecCtx->time_base, pVideoStream->time_base);`

Comment: This seems correct to me. And it should produce the output you want. You should take a look at the packets after the encoding. Especially if the pts values are still what you expect. Sorry that I cannot give you more help

Comment: thanks Mkaes i'll search more, and if i find a news i'll tell you.

Answer (score -1):

When you create the ffmpeg file you have to specify the frame rate
depends on which library you are using but look for something like

```
pCodecContext->time_base.den = frames_per_second;
pCodecContext->time_base.num = 1;
```

Otherwise if you are generating 10-15fps from a webcam but the default in the file is 30 fps it will play back to fast.

See http://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/ for a Qt ffmpeg wrapper

Comment: thanks for the replay, i'm currently using some functions from the Qt ffmpeg wrapper, like in encoding, decoding, and i have just changed the value of  **pCodecContext->time_base.den** even i puted 1 !! but still the same problem

Comment: Either set it in your webcam setup, measure it from a previous run. Or if you are really fussy run the webcam at full speed but throw away images to reduce it to leave exactly one new frame every 'n' millisec. Best option is just to guess that it's 10-15 - the directshow amcap sample or the webcam viewer app will show you