# How to sync between recording and input live video stream?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, directshow, video-capture, video-recording

I am working on a project in which I am receiving raw frames from some input video devices. I am trying to write those frames in a video files using FFMPEG library. 
I have no control over the frame rate i am getting from my input sources. This frame rate varies in run-time also.
Now my problem is how do i sync between recorded video and coming video. Depending upon frame-rate i set in FFMPEG and actual frame rate that i am receiving playback of recorded video is either fast or slow than input video. 
I tried to add timestamps (as numOfFrames) in encoded video as per following link
but that didn't help.

[ffmpeg speed encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858333/ffmpeg-speed-encoding-problem)

Please tell me a way to synchronize both. This is my first time with FFMPEG or any multimedia libraries so any examples will be highly appreciated.

I am using directshow ISampleGrabber interface to capture those frames.
Thank You

Comment: You have timestamps with every frame, what else you need

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't get you. I am working on this for first time. Where am i having time stamp on each frame? Are you referring to ISampleGrabber output ?

Comment: You have frames with `ISampleGrabber::SampleCB `. Each media sample has a time stamp `IMediaSample::GetTime` attached (it is optional, however it is almost always there, or it is a live feed).

Comment: I am working on live feed. Can I use same timestamp in FFMPEG encoding ?

Comment: okay! i did some quick tests `IMediaSample::GetTime` in `SampleCB` is returning  `VFW_E_SAMPLE_TIME_NOT_SET` for me which means this sample is not time stamped. What should i do in this situation ?

Comment: Update: I was using preview pin before that's why it was not giving me any timestamp. Now on capture pin its giving me timestamp values(start time and end time). But i still have no idea about how to use them in FFMPEG encoding. please help !

Comment: As a note, FFmpeg via 'dshow' input can receive from directshow capture devices...

Answer (score 1):

So Finally i figured out how to do this. Here is how..

First i was taking preview from PREVIEW pin of source filter which do not give timestamps to frames. So one should take frames from capture pin of the source filter. Than in `SampleCB` callback function we cant get time using `IMediaSample::GetTime()`. But this function will return time in unit of 100ns. FFMPEG requires it in units of 1/time_base. Here time_base is desired frame rate. 
So directshow timestamp needs to be converted in FFMPEG units first. Than we can set pts in `AVFrame::pts` variable of ffmpeg. One more thing that needs to be considered is first frame of video shoul have timestamp of 0 in FFMPEG so that needs to be taken care of while converting from directshow timestamp to FFMPEG one.

Thank You